# Why my transformation panel doesn't show align to objects to pixel grid option in Illustrator 2020?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

As shown in the picture, there is no such option

[image]

[image]

it will show in the right corner, but it's not clickable.

Comment: This is covered for more recent versions of Illustrator in the duplicate link above.

Answer (score 0):

It is now located in the "hamburger menu" in the upper right corner of the control bar (circled in red here)

[image]

Just click on that and from the dropdown menu select "Snap to Pixel" this will bring up the 2 controls shown below with which you can select the settings you want for pixel snapping

[image]

Also available in the View menu  go View> Snap to Pixel